# Invalid parameters in arcpy Extract by Mask

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst, extract-by-mask, error-000354

I get the following error when I try to extract by mask within a function in my script. When I run the same script separately outside of the function it runs fine. The output is just an intermediate step so I am not looking to save the extracted raster.

ERROR:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 98, in
>    File "", line 20, in PotentialRestoration   File
> "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py",
> line 4237, in ExtractByMask
> return Wrapper(   File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\sa\Utils.py", line 55, in
> swapper
> result = wrapper(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 4230, in
> Wrapper
> result = arcpy.gp.ExtractByMask_sa(   File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing_base.py", line
> 512, in 
> return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True)) arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not
> valid.  ERROR 000354: The name contains invalid characters Failed to
> execute (ExtractByMask).

Code:

```py
def PotentialRestoration():  # Potential Restoration scoring calculation

# To allow overwriting outputs change overwriteOutput option to True.
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
LandcoverData = r"c:\Users\datasets\MCD12C1_2021_MLW.tif"
AU = r"c:\Users\test_data\AU_TM.shp"
Landcover = r"c:Users\projects\Scratch.gdb\Landcover"
Landcover = arcpy.sa.ExtractByMask(LandcoverData, AU, "INSIDE")
```

Comment: Suggest you look at the code [samples](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/extract-by-mask.htm#GUID-C14848CD-0636-4F50-85FE-A6B898664131) for correct syntax?

Comment: I see a missing backslash in the `Landcover` path: `c:Users`

Comment: Apologies the missing backslash is an error from me copying over the code!

Comment: As far as I can tell the syntax is correct as that's what I used to create the code. I haven't included the save output line because I don't want to save as it's an intermediate file